# Campaign Member Process Builder: LeadOrContactOwnerId always null

Tags: process

I am creating a process builder on the Campaign Member object, and as a criteria for an immediate action I need to reference the Owner Id of the associated Lead or Contact. I figured LeadOrContactOwnerId would do it, but it doesn't seem to be working. 
In an attempt to debug, I posted the value of LeadOrContactOwnerId to Chatter, and it appears to be blank.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: `LeadOrContactOwnerId` is one of those SFDC convenience fields that don't actually exist on the sobject

Comment: cropredy, yes, but surely it must have some use?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able traverse to the relationship. When selecting your field, choose `Contact ID >` > `Owner ID` and similarly `Lead ID >` > `Owner ID`.

If you want an alternative solution, you should be able to use a formula like the following:

```
BLANKVALUE(Contact.OwnerId, Lead.OwnerId)
```

Comment: Adrian, I've tried referencing the Lead/Contact OwnerId via the relationships, but one of the relationships will always not be defined and therefore return an access error.

Comment: Can't you write them as separate criteria?

Comment: Yes, but if salesforce is providing me with a more elegant solution why not use it? (I do have workaround using a formula).

Comment: Formula is best in my experience.  PB can throw errors if you try to evaluate field on related object and lookup is null.  It may be better now but in past have had to add criteria that lookup is not null, and the criteria had to be listed before the relationship field to avoid error.

Comment: gorav, that's exactly what I did.

Comment: @JesperBjerrum Did your formula look like what I added? It can be pretty simple. :)

Comment: @AdrianLarson - that's neat. My requirements have since changed a bit, so I'm testing different values depending on whether the campaignmember is a lead or a contact, using IF(NOT(ISBLANK(LeadId))... (btw,, I had to move to using workflow rules instead, since process builder was breaking our integration with eventbrite, and it also made me a bit uneasy that I had to re-write a formula for a formula field because process builder apparently doesn't have full support for formulas).

Comment: @Jesper yeah `BLANKVALUE` is a bit more concise. Sounds like you got it mostly ironed out.

Answer (score -2):

I was able to figure out how to do this in Process Builder.  You need to create a Contact Criteria first with the Condition that `Campaign Member.Lead_ID__c Is null Boolean True`. (I am using the string field that gets populated in Campaign Member)

This means that the Member is a Contact.  I then made the update from the standpoint of using the Contact Record.  No criteria, Field Reference `[Campaign Member].Contact.Owner.Id`.

Then create a second for Lead Criteria and do everything above except Boolean is False.  Update is based on the Lead record. No criteria, Field Reference `[Campaign Member].Lead.Owner:User.Id`.